# Delete pointer error

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm confused as to why after I have created a pointer and try to `delete` it I receive and error message.  The following is some condensed code I've been working with:

```
func()
{
  ptree *resultTree = new ptree;
  resultTree = &getNodeptree(pt);
  delete resultTree;
}

ptree& getNodeptree (ptree &pt)  
{
  BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("root"))
  {
    ptree &temp = v.second;
    return temp;
  }
}
```

From my understanding `resultTree` still needs to be deleted because it's memory is still on the heap.  However, trying to do that produces:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/nathan/Programming/Project_Code/MyBoostXmlTest/Debug/MyBoostXmlTest: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000018347b8 ***
```

Can someone explain why calling `delete` produces an error in this instance?

Comment: pt is Boost Property Tree:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/property_tree.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you delete `resultTree`, you are deleting the memory passed to you from the function call to `getNodeptree`. And you are failing to delete the memory from the explicit call to new.

```
func()
{
  ptree *resultTree = new ptree; // you will need to delete this one
  resultTree = &getNodeptree(pt); // now it points to something else!
  delete resultTree; // now you delete something you shouldn't
}
```

Since `getNodeptree` returns a reference, you really shouldn't be deleting that.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  How about if I removed `= new` from the declaration.  What that resolve this?

Comment: But isn't he getting the address of what the reference refers too? Maybe his problem is that he is deleting something that he shouldn't (maybe `ptree` is a self managing class)

Comment: @johnnyturbo3 Well, you should remove the `new` and also the `delete`.

Comment: @Muggen the problem is that he is deleting something he shouldn't. It is *most likely* undefined behaviour,

Answer (score 2):

You do need to delete the memory, but you overwrite the address you allocated when you reassign the pointer in `resultTree = &getNodeptree(pt);`. I can't understand what's supposed to be happening so I'm afraid I can't offer a suggestion at this time.